# Cant get specific age to display

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Name, doB, Age CURDATE( ) , (
YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F )
) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Ages
SELECT Name, DoB, Ages WHERE Age=20 As Age
FROM Table_
ORDER BY N
```

Where do I put the the `where AGES=20` if I want to only display the names of people  that are 20 years old if the Age column is a temp column?

-- edit --
The oryginal query is:

```
SELECT N, F, CURDATE( ) , 
       ( YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F ) ) 
       - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Age 
FROM edad_ LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Hard to say since the select statement in the question has syntax errors and cannot compile. Please correct the query first.

Comment: SELECT N, F, CURDATE( ) , (
YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F ) ) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Age
FROM edad_
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 2):

I can't make heads or tails of your query.

But to answer your question, a predicate on a derived column is not allowed in a `WHERE` clause, but it can be included in a `HAVING` clause. For example:

```
SELECT t.DoB
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.DoB, CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM mytable t
HAVING age = 20
```

---

*BUT...*

Be aware of performance issues. Note that the HAVING clause is applied very late in the processing of the query, after all of the rows have been retrieved and prepared. It acts more like a filter on the rows that are returned, while the WHERE clause acts as a filter on the rows retrieved, processed much earlier in the query.

For performance on large sets, we typically want to benefit from index range scans, so we use an equivalent predicate on a native column. (If a an appropriate index is available.)

For example, if an index on DoB is available:

```
SELECT t.DoB
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.DoB, CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.DoB >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL -21 YEAR
   AND t.DoB <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL -20 YEAR
```

(NOTE: You may need to replace `>=` with `>` and replace `<` with `<=` to get the age calculation working the way you want on the edge cases of CURDATE is exactly 20 years or exactly 21 years from DoB.)

Comment: Why can't we change this `SELECT t.DoB
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.DoB, CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM mytable t
HAVING age = 20` to `SELECT t.DoB
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.DoB, CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM mytable t
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.DoB, CURDATE()) = 20` ?

Comment: @Akshat: The OP question was how to reference a column alias in a predicate. The change you propose could certainly be made. And in terms of performance, we'd prefer to have our predicates in the `WHERE` and/or `ON` clauses over having them in a `HAVING` clause. For even better performance, we prefer to have predicates that allow for MySQL to use an index range scan, rather than requiring a full scan. Note that MySQL has to evaluate that "age" expression in the `WHERE` clause for every row in the table, which requires a full scan.